# Трехмерные трансформации

Tags: css3, html, javascript

Есть блок:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
<div id='Menu'>
Меню
</div>
</div>
```

Стили к блоку:

```
#wrapper {
    -webkit-perspective: 200px;
    height: 30PX;
    width: 200px;
}
#menu {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(30deg);
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transform: rotateY(30deg);
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transform: rotateY(30deg);
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(115deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateY(30deg);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Необходимо, чтобы при загрузке страницы стили менялись на:

```
transform:rotateY(0deg);
-o-transform:rotateY(0deg);
-webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);
-moz-transform:rotateY(0deg);
-ms-transform:rotateY(0deg);
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: @Kirpich643, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: А головой подумать? Или это сайт добрых услуг, на котором бесплатно напишут решение, за которое Вы наверняка получите деньги?

Comment: У же думал!! Пытался сделать через javascript onLoad="Div()" но ненашол как изменить стили !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
menu.style["-webkit-transform"] = "rotateY(0deg) !important";
```

Но скорее всего у вас не получится сделать так как вы хотите. Вообще, идея странная. Я так понял, надо чтобы сначала одно отработало, потом другое. Тогда надо подождать 0,5 секунды и менять стили. Мало того, браузеры выпендриваются когда происходят подобного рода трансформации стилей. 
Я еще советую делать это не в css, а в style для того чтобы было легче и понятнее работать со стилями при помощи JS. А в CSS заносите статические стили, которых менять не надо.
И лучше всего делать эту операцию через такую очень хитрую конструкцию:

```
var message = "myAnyMessage";
function applyNewStyles() {/* операции изменения стилей*/}

doApplyNew = function(e) {
        if (e.data === message && e.source === window) {
            window.removeEventListener('message', doApplyTo, false);
            applyNewStyles();
        }
};

window.addEventListener('message', doApplyNew, false);
window.postMessage(message, '*');
```

Вот такая странная конструкция помогает выполнит нужные трансформации правильно. Я не понимаю, если честно, что за ахинея, но она помогает. Где-то когда-то нашел проблему и ее решение по поводу изменения стилей "transform" и "translate".

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/163396/javascript-трехмерные-трансформации